# How to pass API response variable from service to multiple controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to pass the API response variable from common service to multiple controllers.

I am getting data in the following API Response.

```
$scope.responseData = reply.data;
```

I am using only for API's in `ApiService`. Here I am using whatever API's I am using in my application.

**API Service :**

```
app.service('apiService', ['$http', function ($http) {
   this.getData = function (userId) {
   return $http.get('myapi' + userId);
 };
}]);
```

**Common Service :**

```
app.service('commonService', ['$window', function ($window) {
  apiService.getData($scope.UserId).then(function (reply) {
    $scope.responseData = reply.data;
    // ...
  });
});
```

**Controllers 1, 2, 3 :**

```
app.controller('firstController', ['apiService', 'commonService',function (apiService, commonService) {
    // ...
      $scope.responseData.forEach(function (data) {
        // do something 
      })
}]);

app.controller('secondController', ['apiService', 'commonService',function (apiService, commonService) {
    // ...
      $scope.responseData.forEach(function (data) {
        // do something 
      })
}]);

app.controller('thirdController', ['apiService', 'commonService',function (apiService, commonService) {
    // ...
      $scope.responseData.forEach(function (data) {
        // do something 
      })
}]);
```

I am using the same loop again and again (`$scope.responseData`) in my controllers, so my application is getting slow. How can I write the code once and use it in multiple controllers? Can anyone please explain to me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$rootScope.$broadcast(/* ... */)`

Something like:

```
app.service('commonService', ['$window', '$rootScope', function ($window, $rootScope) {
apiService.getData($scope.UserId).then(function (reply) {
    $scope.responseData = reply.data;

    $rootScope.$broadcast('onGetData', {value: reply.data});

  $scope.responseData.forEach(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.responseData.forEach(function (data) {
            if (data.Category == 'A') {
                console.log("A");                               
            } else if (data.Category == 'B') {
                console.log("B");                               
            } else if (card.Category == 'C') {
                console.log("C");                               
            }
        })
  });
});
});
```

In your controllers you can write:

```
$scope.$on('onGetData', function(event, data){
   $scope.responseData = data.value;
})
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jQ6YsJbaB0nwYGfY)

Comment: How can I write that if conditions? Am i need to write agian in all controllers?

Comment: no, you get `$scope.responseData`,run in loop on it with your conditions

Comment: and you dont need `$timeout` here

Comment: My controller i am getting error data is not defined. It is not even going inside "onGetData" function.

Comment: be sure that your controllers are initialized before you call `$rootScope.$broadcast('onGetData', {value: reply.data});`